# Is there a way to disable iCloud documents only

Tags: macos, icloud

Does anyone know if there is a way to disable iCloud for documents only? (I am using DropBox and would like all my documents to be in the same place).

I am using Mountain Lion and in my prefs there is an iCloud section where I can untick "Documents & Data". But what's the data part? I only want to disable iCloud documents.

Hope someone can help/clarify.

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having `Documents & Data` active doesn't mean that your documents get saved to iCloud. Some applications might choose to store settings and data that could be shared between your devices. If you disable `Documents & Data` you disable this possibility.

You can always check your iCloud account if there are any documents already saved. Go to 'System Preferences -> iCloud`and click`Manage`. You can here see what applications that are using the storage.

[image]
[image]

You can see that in my case I have documents from Pages and TextEdit. I have chosen to save them there. It's not anything that your computer do automatically.

I'm myself also using Dropbox for documents but I really see no reason to deactivate iCloud `Documents & Data`

Comment: Thanks very much for the thorough answer :)  What I am annonyed about is that some programs default to saving in iCloud, so if I could turn off iCloud document storage my guess is that default behaviour would change. Do you know what the Data in "Documents & Data" stands for?

Comment: If you disable the `Documents & Data` you wont have the options to save there as I wrote. Also applications like TextEdit will open a blank document instead of an "Open file" dialog. The `Data` part is what I wrote above as well - Some application can chose to store settings and small amount of data that could be shared to your iPhone, iPad or another Mac you are using. So far I haven't used any application that do this in OS X so it shouldn't matter if you disable the `Documents & Data` in iCloud settings.